# $\sqrt{x^2-16} - (x-4) = \sqrt{x^2-5x+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

How do I solve this equation I found in my textbook:

> $\sqrt{x^2-16} - (x-4) = \sqrt{x^2-5x+4}$

This is what I tried:

$\sqrt{x^2-16} - (x-4) = \sqrt{x^2-5x+4}$
$\mapsto \sqrt{(x+4)(x-4)} - (x-4) = \sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}$

> Dividing both sides by $\sqrt{x-4}$

$\mapsto \sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x-4} = \sqrt{x-1} $

> Squaring both Sides

$\mapsto x - 2 \sqrt{x^2 - 16}= -1$
$\mapsto \frac{x+1}{2} = \sqrt{x^2 - 16}$

> Squaring both sides

$ \mapsto \frac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{4} = x^2 - 16$
$\mapsto 3x^2 -2x - 65 = 0$

> Solving the quadratic equation

$$x = 5 OR \frac{-13}{3}$$

Checking in the initial equation we can see that $5$ is a valid root. But the second value that is given in the key to the book is $4$. How do I obtain $4$?

Comment: When you divide both sides by $\sqrt{x - 4}$, you get that $\sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x-4} = \sqrt{x-1}$. Now, multiply both sides by its conjugate, namely $\sqrt{x+4} + \sqrt{x-4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain gives $x\geq4$ or $x\leq-4$.

1. $x\leq-4$.

We need to solve $$\sqrt{(4-x)(-4-x)}+\left(\sqrt{4-x}\right)^2=\sqrt{(4-x)(1-x)}$$ or
$$\sqrt{-4-x}+\sqrt{4-x}=\sqrt{1-x}$$ or
$$-4-x+4-x+2\sqrt{x^2-16}=1-x$$ or
$$2\sqrt{x^2-16}=x+1,$$ which has no real roots.

2. $x\geq4.$

We have $$\sqrt{(x-4)(x+4)}=\left(\sqrt{x-4}\right)^2+\sqrt{(x-4)(x-1)},$$ which gives
$$x=4$$ or
$$\sqrt{x+4}=\sqrt{x-4}+\sqrt{x-1},$$ which is
$$x+4=x-4+x-1+2\sqrt{x^2-5x+4}$$ or
$$2\sqrt{x^2-5x+4}=9-x,$$ which gives $$4\leq x\leq9$$ and
$$4(x^2-5x+4)=(9-x)^2$$ or
$$3x^2-2x-65=0,$$ which gives $$x=5$$ and the answer:
$$\{4,5\}.$$

Comment: Could you please explain what 'domain' means?

Comment: The domain of a function $f$ it's a set of all numbers $x$ for which there exist $f(x).$ For example the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ it's $\{x|x\geq0\}$ or $[0,+\infty).$

Answer (score 3):

At the stage where you divided by $\sqrt{x-4}$, you forgot that $\sqrt{x-4}$ could be $0$, which gives the solution $x=4$. You can only divide by $\sqrt{x-4}$ if $x-4\neq 0$.

Comment: But, then without that I was unable to solve the equation itself

Comment: Yes, so just take $\sqrt{x-4}$ out as a factor.

Comment: Or you can treat this case separately: either $x=4$, or we can divide by $\sqrt{x-4}$ to get the equation you have

Comment: Indeed, you can treat the case separately, but it is a good habit to factor, and not divide factors away (loss of information)

Comment: @Math_QED can you please explain?

Comment: What part do you want me to explain?

Comment: 'It is a good habit to factor and not divide the factors away' @Math_QED

Comment: Suppose, for example, that you want to solve the equation: $(x-1)(x-2) = 0$. It is straightforward to see here that: $$(x-1)(x-2) = 0 \iff x = 1 \lor x = 2$$. However, it is true that $(x-1)(x-2) = 0 \implies (x-2) = 0$ (whenever $x \neq 1$), but by dividing this, you lost information, i.e., you lost the information that $x = 1$ is a solution!

Comment: Thanks @Math_QED . I understood completely

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Your equation is the same as
$$\sqrt{(x-4)(x+4)}-\sqrt{(x-4)(x-4)}=\sqrt{(x-4)(x-1)}$$ which gives besides of $x-4=0$ the equation
$$\sqrt{x+4}-\sqrt{x-4}=\sqrt{x-1}\iff4(x^2-16)=(x+1)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this when the equation gets divided by $\sqrt{x-4}$:

$(\sqrt{x-4})(\sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x-4}) - \sqrt{(x-4)(x-1)} = 0$
$\mapsto (\sqrt{x-4})(\sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x-4} - \sqrt{x-1}) = 0$

> $\therefore$ Either $\sqrt{x-4} = 0$ OR $(\sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x-4} - \sqrt{x-1}) = 0$